# Pointer to private data member of a class

Tags: c++

Is it possible to declare a pointer to private data member of a class?  If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 25):

Yes, and the same way you would create any other pointer. The catch is, of course, that since the member is private, you can only create the pointer *inside* the class, where you can see the member.

```
class A 
{
  public:
    int* getFooPtr()
    {
       return &foo;  // OK; Inside the class foo is visible
    }

  private:
    int foo;
};

int main()
{
   A a;

   int* p_foo1 = &a.foo; // Illegal; Outside the class, foo is private
   int* p_foo2 = a.getFooPtr(); // OK; getFooPtr() is a public member function
}
```

So it's possible to create pointers to private members, but only inside the class' member functions, and it is possible to return those created pointers from member functions. Whether or not it's a good idea to return pointers to private members is another question entirely (usually it's not a good idea).

Comment: Mostly correct, except for "only inside the class' member functions" ... `friend` s can expose object internals too :)

Comment: ... as well as static member can be initialized to point to a private member of the class, which is not inside any function.

Answer (score 6):

You can access outside of the declaring class any non-static private member if you are exploiting the fact that C++ allows you to pass the address of the private member in explicit instantiation. However you won't be able to access static private members, since you have to use a pointer to member with this technique.

```
struct A
{
     A() : x("proof!") {}
private:
     char const* x;
};

template class stow_private<A_x,&A::x>;

int main()
{
        A a;

        // Use the stowed private member pointer
        std::cout << a.*stowed<A_x>::value << std::endl;
};
```

You can find the implementation of `stowed<>` and details here:
http://bloglitb.blogspot.hu/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html and 
https://gist.github.com/dabrahams/1528856

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible.  You'd have to return the pointer (or reference) from within the context of the class though, or someone who has `friend` access to the class.  That is because the variable itself is private and so can't be accessed otherwise.

```
class C
{
public:
    int* getXPointer()
    {
        return &x;
    }

    int& getXReference()
    {
        return x;
    }

private:
    int x;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    C c;
    int* p = c.getXPointer();
    int& r = c.getXReference();
    assert(p == &r);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, as the previous answers have demonstrated. But as Tyler McHenry asks, "Is it a good idea?". No, it isn't. The member variables are declared private for a good reason, and subverting the encapsulation in this way will only lead to trouble.

Comment: Whether it's a good idea depends on the scenario.  I think people would be quite unhappy if they couldn't get pointers into a std::vector.

Comment: Hmm. I'd always thought of vectors as containers, but you are right.

Comment: Declaring a pointer to a private member does not necessarily subvert  incapsulation. The only chance when some subversion can happen is when the pointer is more accessible than the member. Nothing in the OP suggests that to be the case.

Comment: No, in fact, this _facilitates_ encapsulation. Because by requiring the class to give out the pointer (or other handle) to the member, the class becomes the arbiter of when the member can be accessed and whether such access has a layer of `const` added to it. I'm not saying situations where this is actually needed are common, but it happens, and when it happens, it promotes encapsulation. In fact, more simply, it doesn't really seem any different than having a getter that gives out a `const&` to some `private` member for whom returning by value/copy would be impossible or pointlessly expensive

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question is rather confusing. When someone says "declare a pointer to *something*", they are usually talking about type-related attributes of a pointer, as in "declare a pointer to `int`". The property of being private does not affect the type of a member at all, meaning that a member of type `int` is always just a member of type `int`, regardless of whether it is public or private. This immediately means that a pointer of type `int *` can always be made to point to a public member of type `int`, or to a private member of type `int`. It doesn't matter at all whether the member is public or private.

Another ambiguity in the wording is that in C++ there are ordinary pointers (like `int *`) and there are pointers of "pointer-to-member" type (like `int MyClass::*`). When you say "a pointer to data member of a class", it is not clear what kind of pointer you are talking about: ordinary or pointer-to-member. However, the above still applies to both kinds: both can easily point to public, protected or private members of the class. Privateness makes no difference.

Again, the property of being "private" does not affect the type of the member, it only affects its accessibility when referred directly, by name. So, in order to make your pointer to point to a private data member of a class you have to initialize that pointer (or assign to it) in an area where that private data member is accessible: inside a method of the owning class or inside a friend function.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: It's not a comment. It is a complete explanation of all the possible interpretations

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, if I understand you right, you'd like to be able to return a pointer to a private member of a class?

```
private:
        int hidden;
    public:
        int& unHide ()
        {
            return hidden;
        }
```

Comment: Why have you specified `mutable`?